# How to add two selectedindices for two listboxes to method that uses type table for handling multiple listbox parameters

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to fetch a dataset that uses two list boxes for building the query.  How to write?

```
public void LoadChecklist(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDEV1"].ConnectionString;
    var SearchResultsTable = new DataTable();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_get_QUADRA_CHECKLIST", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (var dtSIPA = new DataTable())
                {
                    //dtSIPA.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));//assuming you are looking for a list of int values
                    dtSIPA.Columns.Add("SIPA", typeof(string));
                    dtSIPA.Columns.Add("RO", typeof(string));
                    int[] yourSelectedIndexes = ddlSIPA.GetSelectedIndices();
                    int[] yourSelectedIndexes2 = lbRO.GetSelectedIndices();
                    for (int i = yourSelectedIndexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        dtSIPA.Rows.Add(ddlSIPA.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[i]].Value);
                    }
                    for (int j = yourSelectedIndexes2.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    { 
                        dtSIPA.Rows.Add(lbRO.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[j]].Value);
                    }

                    //if (SearchResultsTable.Rows.Count >= 0)
                    //{
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AP_DEV", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CbAPDev.Checked;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROD_DEV", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = cbProdDev.Checked;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ROTYPE", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = ddlROTYPE.SelectedItem.Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SIPA", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dtSIPA;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RO", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dtSIPA;
                    //Response.Write(dtSIPA);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{ ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Selections not found!');", true); }
                }
                try
                {
                    adapter.Fill(SearchResultsTable);
                    GV1.DataSource = SearchResultsTable;
                    GV1.DataBind();
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I should get a dataset back filtered to the selections made in the two list boxes ddlSIPA and lbRO but I'm sure I don't have the code right.

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the 

bounds of the array.

Line 571:                        for (int j =     
yourSelectedIndexes2.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
Line 572:                        { 
Line 573:                     dtSIPA.Rows.Add(lbRO.Items
[yourSelectedIndexes[j]].Value);
Line 574:                        }
Line 575:
```

Source File:  \sw.nos.boeing.com\ewh\dev\VOL01\vanity\qualityvisibility\QUADRA\SAVE_ASSESSMENT.aspx.cs    Line:  573

```
USE [VISIBILITY_BOARD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER On
GO 

 /* Create a table type. */  
CREATE TYPE SIPA_TYPE AS TABLE   
( SIPA NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    RO NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL);  
GO   


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_QUADRA_CHECKLIST] (@AP_DEV bit = '', @PROD_DEV bit = '', @ROTYPE nvarchar(255) = '', @SIPA AS SIPA_TYPE READONLY, @RO AS SIPA_TYPE READONLY) AS


SELECT '' AS QUES_ANSWER
    , '' AS COMMENTS
    , cl.RO_TYPE
    , cl.RO
    , cl.QUES_ID
    , cl.DFQRO AS QDRO
    , cl.QUADRA_QUES

FROM Tbl_QUADRA_CL cl

WHERE (cl.SIPA IN(SELECT SIPA FROM @SIPA) OR (SELECT COUNT(SIPA) FROM @SIPA) = 0)
    AND (cl.RO IN(SELECT RO FROM @RO) OR (SELECT COUNT(RO) FROM @RO) = 0)
    AND (cl.RO_TYPE = @ROTYPE OR @ROTYPE IS NULL)
    AND (cl.AP_DEV = @AP_DEV OR @AP_DEV IS NULL)
    AND (cl.PROD_DEV = @PROD_DEV OR @PROD_DEV IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
     cl.RO_TYPE
    , cl.RO
    , cl.QUES_ID
    , cl.DFQRO
    , cl.QUADRA_QUES
```

Comment: Try debugging and finding the value of `yourSelectedIndexes2.Length` when this error is thrown

Comment: corrected a typo here: Response.Write(yourSelectedIndexes2.Length);
                            dtSIPA.Rows.Add(lbRO.Items[yourSelectedIndexes2[j]].Value);  It still doesn't work as expected and the output values for yourSelectedIndexes2.length = 333 for three selected listbox items.  I'm still lost on why this isn't working.

Comment: I'm sorry but how many are selected? 333 or 3?

Comment: It's combining the values from both listboxes and inserting both values to each variable.  It looks like from SQL Profiler: declare p4 dbo.SIPA_TYPE
insert into p4 values(N'SIPA',NULL)
insert into p4 values(N'Equipment',NULL)
insert into p4 values(N'Automation',NULL)

declare p5 dbo.SIPA_TYPE
insert into p5 values(N'SIPA',NULL)
insert into p5 values(N'Equipment',NULL)
insert into p5 values(N'Automation',NULL)

Comment: only 3 were selected.

Comment: And what is the value of `j` when the error occurs?

Comment: When I select all available listbox items in lbRO, j = 222120191817161514131211109876543210

Answer (score 0):

I found an error.

```
dtSIPA.Columns.Add("SIPA", typeof(string));
dtSIPA.Columns.Add("RO", typeof(string));
int[] yourSelectedIndexes = ddlSIPA.GetSelectedIndices();
int[] yourSelectedIndexes2 = lbRO.GetSelectedIndices();
for (int i = yourSelectedIndexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    dtSIPA.Rows.Add(ddlSIPA.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[i]].Value);
}
for (int j = yourSelectedIndexes2.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{ 
    dtSIPA.Rows.Add(lbRO.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[j]].Value);
}
```

You are adding two columns here, `SIPA` and `RO` but while adding rows for these columns, you are adding the rows separately.

First off the number of selections in the two list boxes `ddlSIPA` and `lbRO` should be the same. Only then can they be added together in a single row.

Your code adds the values of ddlSIPA and bRO as separate rows instead of a single row. Your code should be something like this

```
dtSIPA.Columns.Add("SIPA", typeof(string));
dtSIPA.Columns.Add("RO", typeof(string));
int[] yourSelectedIndexes = ddlSIPA.GetSelectedIndices();// or lbRO.GetSelectedIndices(), they have to be same in count
int[] yourSelectedIndexes2 = lbRO.GetSelectedIndices();
for (int i = yourSelectedIndexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    dtSIPA.Rows.Add(ddlSIPA.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[i]].Value, lbRO.Items[yourSelectedIndexes2[i]].Value);
}
```

Two values have to be added for a single row instead of adding both values as rows.

Comment: I made those changes and now when I select the ddlSIPA listbox values I get:  Index was outside the bounds of the array: dtSIPA.Rows.Add(ddlSIPA.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[i]].Value, lbRO.Items[yourSelectedIndexes2[i]].Value);

Comment: Oh even with your edit the list boxes have to have the same number of selections?  That's not possible in this case.

Comment: Yeah this approach won't work for these two list boxes.  These list boxes have a different number of items in each and have to be able to operate by themselves. Thanks for your suggestion though Najiullah!

Comment: The solution was to remove one of the list boxes.

Comment: If the data in one of the list boxes was not necessary, I guess removing it should have solved it.